# dask.array.apply_gufunc with multiple outputs of different shapes

Tags: dask, python-xarray

I am trying to apply a ufunc to chunked broadcastable dask arrays which produce several outputs of different shapes:

```py
import dask.array as da # dask.__version__ is 1.2.0
import numpy as np

def func(A3, A2):
    return A3+A2, A2**2

A3 = da.from_array(np.random.randn(3,5,5), chunks=(3,2,2))
A2 = da.from_array(np.random.randn(  5,5), chunks=(  2,2))
ret = da.apply_gufunc(func, '(),()->(),()', A3, A2, output_dtypes=[float,float])

for r in ret:
    print(r)
    r.compute()
```

The problem is that both outputs in `ret` are assumed to be of shape (3,5,5), which then fails on `.compute()` with `ValueError: axes don't match array` for the second output, which should be 2-dimensional.

How can I use `apply_gufunc` in this case?

**Note:** I would probably rather use `xarray.apply_ufunc` in this case but unfortunately it is not available yet with multiple outputs (see [here](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/1815)).

Comment: Yeah, got the "tumbleweed" badge for that question \o/

Comment: Unfortunately there are not very many maintainers who are familiar with gufunc semantics @shoyer is your best bet, but I think he's quite busy these days.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround that helps:

```
def func(A3, A2):
    return A3+A2, (A2**2)[np.newaxis,:]
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround! The problem is that all outputs get coerced to the same shape, thus `ret[1].shape == (3, 5, 5)`. It would like it to remain of shape `(5, 5)`, or at least `(1, 5, 5)`.